# How can I disable ReCaptcha verification during mobile number verification in my Android Flutter Firebase app?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I just want to remove ReCaptcha verification from my app.

every time I verify my mobile number, a default browser opens for device verification

> Also enable Google Play Integrity API in the Firebase console.
> my google JSON file is up to date in android studio.
> Added SHA1 and SHA-256 in my firebase.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you are running the app in debug mode it will be asking for the re captcha verification every time